# The slang term for books made of paper

Tags: word-request, american-english, slang

What is slang for a book that has pages made of paper; the opposite of an ebook? I used to know. It's something like "tree book", which I know is wrong, but I can't come up with anything better. A *printed book* must be discarded because it's neither slang nor humorous.

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=slang+for+book+that+has+pages+made+of+paper+the+opposite+of+an+ebook&sca_esv=571840155&sxsrf=AM9HkKm1FsbTP-hKtwJNehC8RGESXC3p4g%3A1696849077176&ei=tdwjZd-aCrD97_UP4oSI6As&ved=0ahUKEwifye2z5-iBAxWw_rsIHWICAr0Q4dUDCBA&oq=slang+for+book+that+has+pages+made+of+paper+the+opposite+of+an+ebook&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiRHNsYW5nIGZvciBib29rIHRoYXQgaGFzIHBhZ2VzIG1hZGUgb2YgcGFwZXIgdGhlIG9wcG9zaXRlIG9mIGFuIGVib29rSABQAFgAcAB4AZABAJgBAKABAKoBALgBDMgBAOIDBBgAIEE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) did not help me much. (sad emoji)

Comment: "real" book :-(

Comment: I suggest no such term exists, and if it did the simple exercise of explaining how it could would bring it back to mind. To me, even Mike M's 'real book' gives too much latitude since the object in Question is simply a 'book' and an 'e-book' is comparable only in a very general sense.

Comment: A *cis-book*, possibly?

Comment: It would be called a "book", as opposed to an "ebook".

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The slang term is...

> **dead trees**  [<sup>(techopedia.com)</sup>](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/23350/dead-tree-edition)
> ***Dead tree edition** is a slang term used to describe any publication that comes in printed form, even when there is a paperless edition available.*

Comment: +1 And to note that the wording from that source is poor because it allows for an e-book to be called "dead tree edition" if it happens to also come in printed form. For instance, the e-book "50 Shades of Grey" also now comes in printed form, but it's incorrect to call the e-book form a "dead tree edition". I'd state it: "*...any publication in printed form when there is also a paperless edition available*".

Comment: @gotube Isn't the normal term "dead tree format' which also avoids the issue in your comment

Comment: @mmmmmm It's the definition I have issues, with, not the term itself.

Comment: Personally I prefer it properly hyphenated: ‘a _dead-tree book_’ or ‘the _dead-tree edition_’.

Comment: (Also note that the term probably carried more stigma when first coined than it does now.  I remember the days when ‘saving trees’ was the thing, and we were encouraged to use plastic bags and suchlike to avoid squandering trees!  These days, of course, we tend to have a broader understanding, and take into account that trees are both renewable and biodegradable, while plastics are mostly neither…)

Comment: @gidds I think you're being overly critical. It doesn't say "also comes in printed form" or "may come in printed form". It's describing that specific edition, just as you might have "paperback edition" and "hard-cover edition".

Comment: @mmmmmm: [Ngrams not found: **dead-tree format**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dead-tree+edition%2Cdead-tree+format&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)  clearly shows that the "standard" expression is *dead-tree **edition***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That may be an artifact of the corpus that N-grams searches which under-ranks casual usages. I've only seen "dead tree format" or "dead tree form", but also only in an online context.

Comment: @gotube A different reading of "a publication", I think. The difference between "a publication" meaning all editions, volumes, etc., of something, vs. meaning one specific instance. With the latter meaning it seems clear enough that only the versions actually on paper count as dead tree editions.

Comment: @user3067860 When does "publication" mean a single instance?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally choose to use what is called [contrastive focus reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication) (thank you, [Vsauce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9ak89FwYeI), for that one) and call it a **book book**.

Answer (score 3):

#### Hard Copy

Although not typically applied to books, the slang term [hard copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_copy), would, when contrasted with an e-book, be immediately understood within context to mean the printed-on-paper version of the book.  As the link explains, 'hard copy' is a neutral term while the '**dead tree** edition' [suggested by](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/342506/20756) FunbleFingers is a pejorative term for the same idea.

You might also use **print copy**, **print version**, or **paper copy**.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer but "hard copy" is not slang.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Since the paper is neither literally hard, nor is this sense using the term in its original sense of "a manuscript or typewritten document that has been edited and proofread and is ready for typesetting or being read on-air in a...broadcast", I would consider using hard copy to refer to a book as slang. Of course, as the querent, it is what _you_ mean by slang that matters, but since [that doesn't seem to be very well defined on this stack](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/what-is-slang), making your own definition explicit would help potential answerers.

Comment: Books that have physical  pages and either hard or soft covers could be referred to as hard copies I suppose, but I was looking for a term that was slang (very informal language usually uttered and  created by a group of native speakers e.g teenagers) and humorous. The term "hard copy" is well-established across all English dialects, quite formal and not humorous,

Comment: I believe that the meaning of slang is communally understood, and easy enough to look up in any dictionary. The user's post you linked is really asking if their question was downvoted because they misused the tag "slang". No one disputed that person's analysis or definition of the term "slang" and the tag "slang" was consequently  left alone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the term '[pulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_(paper))' perhaps.  It does have a certain connation relative to books that may or may not fit your needs:

[pulp (noun 5):](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pulp)

> a magazine or book on cheap paper and often dealing with sensational material